# re-run failed dagRun in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have few failed dagRuns related to a dag. I want to re-run them programatically later. below is my code.

```
            dag_runs_list=dr.find(dag_id=env_dag_id, run_id = dag_run_id)
            print(dag_runs_list)
            
            assert len(dag_runs_list) == 1
            if dag_runs_list[0].state == DagRunState.FAILED:
                dag_runs_list[0].set_state(DagRunState.RUNNING)
```

But it is not changing the state of dag_runs.

Comment: Do you use retries on the tasks?

Comment: I have to re-run them using some other dag-runs.